# How to set "UPDATE SET NOT NULL"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a problem with `UPDATE` statements:

```
UPDATE tmp_gelbe_seten SET haus_nr_von =  ubstring(hausnummer,'([0-9]*)') WHERE hausnummer like '%-%'; 

UPDATE tmp_gelbe_seten SET haus_nr_bis = substring(hausnummer,'-([0-9]*)') WHERE hausnummer like '%-%';

UPDATE tmp_gelbe_seten SET haus_nr_von = substring(hausnummer,'([0-9]*)') WHERE hausnummer like '%/%'; 

UPDATE tmp_gelbe_seten SET haus_nr_bis = substring(hausnummer,'/([0-9]*)') WHERE hausnummer like '%/%';
```

If I run them one after another than they overwrite each other. How can I prevent it?

With Regards

Andrey

Comment: They only overwrite eachother if you have a house number containing both `-` and `/`, because otherwise your `where` clause ensures that at most one of the `update` statements sets `haus_nr_von` for any specific row, and only one sets `haus_nr_bis` for any specific row. If you do have house numbers containing both `-` and `/`, what do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a conditional SET clause:

```
update tmp_gelbe_seten 
  set haus_nr_von = case 
                       when hausnummer like '%-%' then substring(hausnummer,'([0-9]*)') 
                       when hausnummer like '%/%' then substring(hausnummer,'([0-9]*)')
                    end,
      haus_nr_bis = case
                       when hausnummer like '%-%' then substring(hausnummer,'-([0-9]*)')
                       when hausnummer like '%/%' then substring(hausnummer,'/([0-9]*)')
                    end
where hausnummer like '%-%' 
   or hausnummer like '%/%';
```

Note that the `where` clause is important to only select those rows that you actually want to change. Performance is one reason and correctness the other. If you leave that out, the `CASE` statements will return NULL if the `hausnummer` doesn't match any condition. If you *do* leave the `where` clause out, you **have** to add an `ELSE` part returning the column to be updated so that the current value is not changed `else haus_nr_von` and `else haus_nr_bis`

As the expression for `haus_nr_von` is the same in both cases, the above statement can be simplified to:

```
update tmp_gelbe_seten 
  set haus_nr_von = substring(hausnummer,'([0-9]*)'),
      haus_nr_bis = case
                       when hausnummer like '%-%' then substring(hausnummer,'-([0-9]*)')
                       when hausnummer like '%/%' then substring(hausnummer,'/([0-9]*)')
                    end
where hausnummer like '%-%' 
   or hausnummer like '%/%';
```

Comment: Tnx a lot . That was exactly what i looked for.